# How to use keyboard bind correctly?

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, keyboard, bind

I wanted to write a program that would allow using textinput and keyboard bind at the same time. But when I click on the text input widget, an error occurs. How do I rewrite the code so that it doesn't exist? (the problem is related to python kivy)

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):   
        self.my_keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(self.my_keyboard_down, self.root)
        self.my_keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self.my_keyboard_down)
        
        widget = FloatLayout()
        
        text_input = TextInput(multiline=False)
        widget.add_widget(text_input)

        print_text = lambda arg: print(text_input.text)
        widget.add_widget(Button(on_press = print_text, size_hint = [0.2, 0.2], text = 'press pls'))

        return widget

    def my_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        if keycode[1] == 'escape': quit()
        if keycode[1] == 'right': print('right')
        if keycode[1] == 'left': print('left')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Always try to include the error messages you get in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, when you click on the `TextInput`, the `TextInput` calls your  `my_keyboard_down()`, but with no args. You can work around this by defining your `my_keyboard_down()` with variable args:

```
# def my_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
def my_keyboard_down(self, *args):
    if len(args) == 0:
        return
    else:
        keyboard = args[0]
        keycode = args[1]
        text = args[2]
        modifiers = args[3]
    if keycode[1] == 'escape': quit()
    if keycode[1] == 'right': print('right')
    if keycode[1] == 'left': print('left')
```

I suspect this is a bug in the `TextInput`.